# Laravel 5: AJAX Requests & Validation

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2 docs state:

> AJAX Requests & Validation
>
> In this example, we used a traditional form to send data to the
>   application. However, many applications use AJAX requests. When using
>   the validate method during an AJAX request, Laravel will not generate
>   a redirect response. Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response
>   containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be
>   sent with a 422 HTTP status code.

Src: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/validation#quick-ajax-requests-and-validation

However, this doesn't seem correct. A simple CURL call to a route using validation, still returns HTML/a redirect:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache" 
-d '{}' "http://yours.com/user/register"
```

The response of the above is HTML, and a redirect. It's not JSON.

Even this page: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#retrieving-input states:

> Retrieving JSON Input Values
>
> When sending JSON requests to your application, you may access the
>   JSON data via the input method as long as the Content-Type header of
>   the request is properly set to application/json.

So what have we missed? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also seem to need the following header:

```
"X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest"
```

Thus:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 
-H "X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest" 
-H "Cache-Control: no-cache"
-d '{}' "http://yours.com/user/register"
```

And now `$this->validate(...)` is properly returning a JSON response.